# How to add Linq support in SQL CLR

Tags: linq, sqlclr

It is my understanding that System.Core.dll and System.Xml.Linq.dll are supported (or will be) in SQL server 2008.

I am trying to use Linq to Objects in my SQL 2008 CLR project.

How would I go about "adding" / registering those dlls? (I can't add them as references)

Thanks in advance,
Orry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLCLR projects don't seem to provide the "Add reference" menu item, but Power Commands for Visual Studio at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands provides an easy workaround.

1) Install the power commands.

2) Create another, non-SQLCLR project, and add those references to it. If you already have a project with those references in the solution, skip this & just use it.

3) Right click on each desired reference from #2, and select *Copy reference*. Go to the references node of your SQLCLR project and select *Paste reference*.

Note well that you cannot just reference any old DLL; there's a pretty narrow pre-approved list of allowed dlls. See e.g. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/post/New-SQLCLR-approved-assembly-in-SP1.aspx for more on that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [referencename]

FROM 'filepath'

WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

Then right click your project, click add references, and it should show up under SQL server.